# Can’t Enable Apple Watch Auto-Unlock

Tags: macos, security, unlock, apple-watch

With macOS Sierra installed on a Mac from at least 2013 and an Apple Watch (the very first one), users should be able to unlock their Mac with their Apple Watch. I have an Early 2013 MacBook Pro and an Apple Watch, both of which have the most updated version of the OS installed. I followed [these instructions](http://www.cultofmac.com/441405/how-to-use-apple-watch-to-unlock-your-mac-in-macos-sierra/) to get it to work (checked 2 factor authentication is on, I have a password on my Watch), but I do not see the option to use my Watch to unlock under System Preferences. Any ides on why it does not work? Could it have something to do with me having 2 Apple IDs, one for iTunes and one for iCloud? Could it be my Mac is somehow not ready for this feature (although it is from 2013)?

Comment: It could be a bug that will be resolved when the OS is officially released tomorrow.

Comment: That article you linked was from a beta version so maybe they changed something for the release?  Take a look at [this recent article](http://www.macrumors.com/how-to/macos-sierra-apple-watch-unlock/) and see if following those steps help.

Comment: Yes, you need to be signed in to the same AppleID.

Comment: You says you have an Early-2013 MBP, on the page that @Harv linked in his answer, https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT206995, it says it needs an Mid-2013 or later MBP, maybe that is the case?

Comment: @TomShen Yes I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing the `"Allow your Apple Watch to unlock your Mac"` checkbox?

You may need to enable Continuity.  Make sure both devices are on the same WiFi network, and Bluetooth is enabled.  The article also had an error, it says

> "[...] make sure that Disable Automatic Login is unchecked. If the
>   option is grayed out, you might need to click the padlock icon at the
>   bottom of the window to make the necessary changes."

I think they meant that the box is **checked**.

EDIT: Here's the Apple article you want to reference: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT206995

Comment: I do not see that checkbox. And I know why... The article you linked says I need a mid-2013 Mac. I have an early-2013 one... That is sad.